# warning C4047: '=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [2]'

Tags: c

Whenever I compile my program I get one error: warning C4047. I'm very new to programming in this language and don't understand what the problem is or how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

The error is specifically on line `word[x - 1] = "i";`

```
void RuleOne(char word[], char plural[]) {

    int x = strlen(word);

    word[x - 1] = "i";

    plural = strcat(word, "es");

}
```

Comment: `word[x - 1] = 'i';` Note single quotes.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag because this problem does not exist in C++. With C++ you would get outright failure to compile (a compilation error), not a warning. To compile as C++ with the Microsoft compiler, rename your source code file from ".c" to ".cpp".

Comment: Please don't tag your questions with other languages than the one (or ones) you're using. It misleads people who are led here via search engines such as Google.

Answer (score 6):

```
word[x - 1] = "i";
```

`"i"` is a **string literal**, not a **character constant**.

Use single quotes if you want characters:

```
words[x - 1] = 'i';
               ^ ^
```

Besides, you're doing it wrong with `plural`. This is a wrong job:

```
plural = strcat(word, "es");
```

You're actually appending `"es"` to `word` and let the pointer `plural` point to the same address as `word`, which is obviously not what you intended to do. Try copying `word` the append `es` to the replica:

```
strcpy(plural, word);
strcat(plural, "es");
```

Since `strcpy()` returns the copied string (buffer), you can put it inside `strcat()`:

```
strcat(strcpy(plural, word), "es");
```

Though, I recommend not doing so before you fully understand how it works.

Comment: @TchalyLeandreJr. You can always accept answers you deem useful by clicking the grey tick beside it.

Answer (score 0):

There are *two* problems in your code

1) Indeed as iBug mentioned

```
words[x - 1] = 'i'; // not "i"
```

2) `plural` is not set to the plural version

```
// instead of >> plural = strcat(word, "es");
strcpy(plural, word);
strcat(plural, "es");
```

is what you want.